# mark_for_destruction with nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, before-save

In my application I am using `mark_for_destruction` to remove nested records on the basis of condition.

I have a `Ticket` model and a `Pick` model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picks
  attr_accessible :picks_attributes

  before_save :mark_destroy_zero_weighted_picks

  def mark_destroy_zero_weighted_picks
    picks.each do |pick|
      pick.mark_for_destruction if pick.weight.to_i == 0
    end
  end
end

class Pick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
  attr_accessible :ticket_id
  attr_accessible :weight
end
```

If there is a ticket with 4 picks associated to it, having weight `1,0,2,1`; then only the first pick gets saved and all other picks after the `0` weighted pick (for which `marked_for_destruction` is true) are removed when creating a new ticket record. It works fine if I edit the record but does not work while creating a new record.

Comment: If you want fast decision you can change before_save to after_save filter, i guess it helps.

Comment: Do you want to reject just picks that have a 0 weight, or are you really trying to reject the pick with the 0 weight and all the picks that come after it?

Comment: @cbascom: i just want to reject the picks with 0 weight only but the adjacent pick also gets deleted. I have also created a small app that illustrates the problem: https://github.com/aman199002/rails_issue.Try to create a new ticket record with nested picks providing weight attribute 1, 0, 4, 6 respectively.It should remove the second pick as it is weighted 0 and other 3 picks should be saved in the database. But the next adjacent pick to the 0 weighted pick also gets deleted i.e only the first and last picks are saved having weight 1 & 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like there was a bug in rails 3.2.3 - I don't see this problem with 3.2.12 but I'm not sure when it got fixed.

That said, an easier way to approach this may be to use the reject_if option for accepts_nested_attributes_for:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picks,
    :reject_if => lambda { |attributes| attributes[:weight].to_i == 0 },
    :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :picks_attributes
end
```

This will silently reject all new picks that have a weight of 0.  The only thing it doesn't address is the update case if you want existing picks to be deleted when they are updated to have a weight of 0, but you have a remove pick link to allow for that anyway.

Comment: Yes this bug was specific to rails version. Working fine with rails 3.2.12. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8585#issuecomment-14013135

Comment: You agreed with my answer but you unaccepted it.  Was that a mistake, or are you looking for some other information?

Comment: actually, that is a weird bug due to rails version which was not explained properly by rails contributor also. Anyways your answer also states the solution, so i will mark it correct.